# Get boolean array indicating which elements in array which belong to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

This seems to be a simple question but I am struggling with errors from quite some time.
Imagine an array

```
a = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
```

I want to test which elements in the array belong to another list

```
[2,3,6]
```

If I do

```
a in [2,3,6]
```

Python raises "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

In return, i would like to get a boolean array-like

```
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Please can you give an example of what your output should look like, including what data type the output should be (e.g. is it a list or a numpy array?) Also please say whether `a` is always 1-dimensional, or if it can have more dimensions, then to include an example of the output in that case.

Comment: Currently there are two answers on offer, one producing `array([[0], [1], [4]])` and the other `[0, 1, 4]`, and it is impossible to know which one is more suitable because the requirements have not been stated. This is why it is important for the question to state what output is required.

Comment: Hi @alaniwi, Thanks for your comments. I would would prefer a boolena array in return. e.g. [True, True, False, False, True].

Comment: The array can also have more than 1 dimension. So a boolean array can be saved for selection of data at later stages

Comment: Thank you for adding the return type. I have suggested an edit to the question to remove the bit about "the index of...", because it implies that you want integers relating to the position on the list, which contradicts what you say about wanting a boolean array. Anyway, you will see that one of the answers produces your desired boolean array as an intermediate to calculating the array of indices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to create a *boolean mask* then use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) on this mask to find the indices of array elements that are non-zero:

```
m = np.isin(a, lst)
indices = np.argwhere(m)
```

---

```
# print(m)
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True])

# print(indices)
array([[0], [1], [4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
arr2 = np.array([2,3,6])
arr_result = [bool(a1 in arr2) for a1 in arr1]
print(arr_result)
```

I have used simple list-comprehension logic to do this.

Output:

```
[True,True,False,False,True]
```